# How does gmail know where I copied an image from

Tags: javascript, html, gmail, filereader

When I copy an image to the clipboard and paste it in an email in gmail, it pastes an image with a src of the location I copied it from.

I tried finding that property in the `onpaste` callback but it doesn't seem to be there. How does gmail do it?

You can test it out with the animated gif on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_%28graphic%29)

You can play with the `onpaste` callback [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zbC9h/)

Comment: Hm, for me it shows the picture copied...  What browser are you using, and how are you copying the image to the clipboard?